# What happens to the H electron during acid reaction?

Tags: acid-base, protons

In this generic acid-base reaction:

$\ce{HX + B <=> X- + HB+}$

It's explained that the acid HX donates a proton H+ to its conjugate base HB+.  What happens to the electron that was originally in the acid's H atom?

Comment: "What happens to the electron that was originally in the acid's H atom?" It's stuck as an extra electron with the $X$ atom, and that explains why $\ce{X}$ ends up with a uninegative charge.

Answer (score 2):

The electron belonging to elemental hydrogen forms part of a covalent bond with $\ce{X}$. In this acid-base reaction the $\ce{HX}$ bond breaks *heterolytically*, meaning that both electrons constituting the bond go to $\ce{X-}$, hence the negative charge.

[image]

The base then donates electrons to the proton, forming the electron deficient species $\ce{HB+}$.

Comment: Thanks!!  why can't they just say that in the textbook??

Comment: I'm not sure what level you're working at or what textbook you're using but [this page](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/theories.html) has some diagrams that you might find helpful. Otherwise, if you feel I've answered your question, please consider [accepting my answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)